# Event when mouse leaves is not detected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `div` which should change the content it renders when the mouse enters its surface or leaves it:

The `div` is connected to these methods:

```
  mouseOut: function() {
    console.log("Mouse out!!!");
    this.setState({flipped: false});
  },

  mouseOver: function() {
    console.log("Mouse over!!!");
    this.setState({flipped: true});
  },
```

The `onMouseOver` event works well. However, `onMouseOut` has no effect and it looks like the `mouseOut` function is not called.

Instead of `mouseOut` I also tried `onMouseLeave` and `onMouseDown` but still there is no effect`.

How can I make the React component detect that the mouse has moved out?

Comment: you should make a demo fiddle so that we can help you with it.

Comment: w/o looking at your component is impossible to know whats wrong, also what browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There must be something wrong in the way you wire parts of your code together, because those two methods seem perfectly fine.

Here is a working example in JSFiddle:

[React mouseOver and mouseOut](https://jsfiddle.net/iaretiga/dn3tm3Lh/1/)

Try to compare this to your code, maybe you can spot the difference. Things that can go wrong:

- You misspell your prop names. Event handlers are camelCase - if you accidentally use the wrong case, for example `mouseout`, they will be ignored.
- You accidentally assign the return value of your function instead of the function itself, e.g. `mouseOut={this.mouseOut()}` - the prop will be undefined, nothing will be called.